# How to check that KafkaConsumer still has assigned partitions without reading more data with poll()

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In my KafkaConsumer app I want to read a batch of messages with poll() and process them. But processing may fail. In this case I want to retry until I succeed but only retry if consumer still owns partitions. I don't want to constantly call poll() because I don't want to read more data.

This is a code snippet:

```
consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerConfig);
try {
    consumer.subscribe(config.topics() /** Callback does not work as I do not call poll in between */ );
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<byte[], Value> values = consumer.poll(10000);
        while (/* I am still owner of partitions */) {
            try {
                process(values);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("I dont care, just retry while I own the partitions", e)
            }
        }
    }
} catch (WakeupException e) {
    // shutting down
} finally {
    consumer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a conclusion that it is impossible to call poll() without reading messages with current kafka consumer 10.2.x. However, it is possible to update offset after a processing failure. So I update offset as if the messages were never read

```
while (!stopped) {
   ConsumerRecords<byte[], Value> values = consumer.poll(timeout);
    try {
        process(values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        rewind(records);
        // Ensure a delay after errors to let dependencies recover
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

and rewind method is

```
private void rewind(ConsumerRecords<byte[], Value> records) {
    records.partitions().forEach(partition -> {
        long offset = records.records(partition).get(0).offset();   
        consumer.seek(partition, offset);
    });
}
```

It solves the initial problem

Answer (score 1):

There is a callback method that tells you when your consumers partition assignments are about to be revoked. Keep processing message unless you get an onPartitionRevoked() event.

https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRebalanceListener.html#onPartitionsRevoked(java.util.Collection)

Comment: But how is this callback method going to be called? From which thread?

Comment: It’s believe it’s called by the main Kafka Consumer client thread. Try it out. It is recommended that you implement this callback anyway so you don’t lose your offset and end up reprocessing messages upon a rebalance.

Comment: The main KafkaConsumer client thread is trying to process resources running `process(values);` in a loop, isn't it?

Comment: Yes but it’s not blocked so it can still receive async callbacks. If your process(values) is getting blocked on an external resource then you might want to do your processing in one or more processing threads separate from the consumer thread.

Comment: Is the callback being called from inside the poll() call from main consumer thread? This is exactly what I'm going to avoid as I don't want to call poll() and read more data if consumer is still subscribed to partitions. Or is it called from a separate thread? Then I want to read the documentation about kafka consumer threads as I only know about the main consumer thread and healthcheck thread. But healthcheck thread should not call the callback.

Answer (score 1):

What about simply calling `assignment()` ?

http://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#assignment()

Comment: I tried but looks like assignment() gives back the last assigned partitions, but does not check if rebalancing happened and partitions are revoked